# Help------ -dumpprivkey gives key connected to different address

Tags: bitcoind

So I bought my first bitcoin yesterday and I generated my first address which is the one I used to receive the bitcoins. Now since I am still trying to sync, I have no idea if I received these coins as I cannot access the address using the directory. I checked blockchain and it says the address received the money but I can only view it as a spectator as Bitcoin Core is giving me the wrong private key. When i bounce between commands it always comes back to this random address that it has now added to my list of receiving address'. I find this very odd as the address that received the money is part of the address' connected to my wallet, but its as if the first address was overridden or something. Do you guys think there is any hope? Any insight is much appreciated thanks

Comment: -getaccount "address A" gives account A, then -getaccountaddress "account A" gives address B. Then the account name for B is different rhen what it displayed before.

Comment: -dumpprivkey is different to -getaccount. I am pretty sure that -getaccountaddress just gives you an address for the account, not necessarily all addresses for the account. There are lots of receiving addresses pre-made by the software. `-dumpprivkey {address}` should work correctly if you want your priv key to import into Electrum.

Comment: I know, but shouldn't -dumpprivkey display the correct private key and not the private key to a different address? I even tried every qr code on bitaddress.org and nothing matches up. This is very odd as no one else seems to have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can install a lightweight wallet to your phone, this will work much faster than since it doesn't need to download the full blockchain and verify it.
Then you can import the private key and you will be able to use your bitcoins.

Some options:

- electrum.org
- exodus.io
- Mycelium
- GreenAddress

Not all of them support all operating systems but together they cover Windows, Mac, Linux, Android and iOS.

Comment: Yes as soon as I figure out what went wrong and if I can access the coins on that address I will use a webwallet